# Bootstrap - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined on checkbox click

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I have a simple mvc table in my cshtml page where I am trying to add a checkbox in one of the columns but I am getting following error wheh I am clicking on the checkbox:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Now this error is coming from bootstrap.js file:

```
 b.prototype.click = function(b) {
        var c = a(b.currentTarget).closest("tr").find(this.options.target)[0];
        if (a(b.target)[0] !== c)
            if (b.preventDefault(),
            c.click)
                c.click();
            else if (document.createEvent) {
                var d = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                d.initMouseEvent("click", !0, !0, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null),
                c.dispatchEvent(d)
            }
    }
```

I can see that the value of "c" is undefined and due to that, it throws the error. If I comment bootstrap.js file from the layout page. Everything is ok.

Here is my table:

```
  <table id="DashboardTab" class="table table-striped rowlink table-hover" data-link="row">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Groups
            </th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        
        @{var i = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="display: none">@item.Id</td>
                <td>
                     @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
                <td>
                     <i>All</i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.IsStd)
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBox("Active" + i, item.IsActive.Value)
                    }
                </td>
                <td style="display: none">@item.IsStandard</td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }

    </table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
So the issue is because of "data-link="row". Actually the row is clickable and thus, clicking on checkbox acts like a row click. How can I only make few rows clickable and not all?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was because of the data-link=row in the table. I needed only few rows to be clickable so I removed `data-link=row` from table and in the  in added onclick() event:

```
if(item.IsStd){
  <tr onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action( "Edit", "Home",new {id = item.ID})'">
}
```